# votos de negativação em serie

Tags: debate

Boa tarde a todos, recentemente perdi uma boa quantidade de reputação repentinamente, apesar de não ter estourado o limite diário e nem ter recebido up votes em série de algum usuário em minhas perguntas e respostas, o quê aconteceu foi a perda de reputação em perguntas que havia feito e que já havia marcado como respondidas...

Segue o print

[image: Perguntas negativadas]

Esses votos ocorreram em uma faixa de 5 minutos mais ou menos...
Sei que o sistema da stackoverflow pode reverter esses down votes em série porém, existe algum tipo de penalidade para a pessoa que o pratica?

acho justo que up votes em serie sejam revertidos e mais justo ainda quando são down votes, porém acredito que seria justo uma penalidade ao praticante, tanto do down vote quanto dos up vote em serie...

Comment: É um comportamento bem triste, e que infelismente não têm consequências para quem o faz visto que são votos negativos a perguntas. Penso que não dá para saber quem foi. Vamos ver o que dizem os moderadores com as ferramentas que têm.

Comment: RodrigoBorth pensa pelo lado positivo, alguém aqui te dá muita importância. Como dizia o outro "falem bem ou mal de mim, o que interessa é que falem" ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. eu sou daqueles que acredita que não existe marketing ruim, falando bem ou falando mal o marketing só aumenta meu ibope :D

Comment: E para constar, os votos em serie foram revertidos essa madrugada :D

Comment: Tem um job que roda em todos os stacks que reverte votos em série, sejam positivos ou negativos. Não sei se pode ser desativado por stack, nem se está funcionando no SOpt.

Comment: @Renan, não tem sentido desativar esse job, duvido inclusive que exista essa opção no painel administrativo.

Comment: Esse é o melhor job que conheço da stack

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Já estamos investigando.

Confirmada a infração, vamos advertir o usuário via e-mail.

Havendo reincidência, os moderadores tem mecanismos de suspensão ou, em último caso, podemos banir o usuário.

Nosso objetivo é garantir um bom clima na comunidade, a boa convivência entre os usuários e que os votos sejam dados de acordo com a qualidade da postagem e não de acordo com a pessoa que a escreveu.

Infelizmente, esta não é a primeira vez que isso acontece (eu mesmo já fui vítima disso), nem será a última. O importante é seguir em frente e não desanimar.

Comment: Bom, fico mais tranquilo sabendo que em caso de denuncia ocorre uma notificação e até mesmo penalidade